# What is the uma_authorization role in Keycloak?

Tags: oauth, keycloak

The role `uma_authorization` is apparently created by default in Keycloak. What is this role? Can I safely delete it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UMA - User-Managed Access.

Keycloak [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_user_managed_access).

Comment: It would be good if the answer actually addressed what the "uma_authorization" role is (as opposed to what "UMA" is – and there isn't any mentions to "uma_authorization" in the linked docs), why Keycloak creates it by default, and whether it can be safely deleted.

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Answer (score 10):

To answer the question, it's for something called [User-Managed Access](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_user_managed_access), which Keycloak Supports.

By default, the [feature is not enabled](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_authorization_my_resources) - but you can do so by going to **Realm Settings > General Tab** (the first tab) and toggling it. Since you're likely not using it, you can remove it.